# How to return arrays in which a specific column contains non-empty value in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like below:

```
$array =    [    

    0 => [  
        "id"    =>  1,  
        "name"  => "Sammy",
        "phone" => "2348055643322",
        "email" => "sammy@abc.com"
    ],  
    1 => [  
        "id"    => 2,  
        "name"  => "Saheed",  
        "phone" => "",
        "email" => "saay@aol.com"
    ], 
    2 => [  
        "id"    => 3,  
        "name"  => "Edwin",  
        "phone" => "2348099993322",
        "email" => "eddy@gmail.com"
    ],
    3 => [  
        "id"    => 3,  
        "name"  => "Jonadab",  
        "phone" => "2348066773322",
        "email" => "jonadab@gmail.com"
    ],
    4 => [  
        "id"    => 3,  
        "name"  => "Mercy",  
        "phone" => "",
        "email" => "mercy@sysnet.com"
    ]

   ];
```

Any idea about what would be the fastest and most efficient way to return only array with non empty PHONE value i.e. I would like the resulting array to be:

```
$array =    [    

    0 => [  
        "id"    =>  1,  
        "name"  => "Sammy",
        "phone" => "2348055643322",
        "email" => "sammy@abc.com"
    ], 
    2 => [  
        "id"    => 3,  
        "name"  => "Edwin",  
        "phone" => "2348099993322",
        "email" => "eddy@gmail.com"
    ],
    3 => [  
        "id"    => 3,  
        "name"  => "Jonadab",  
        "phone" => "2348066773322",
        "email" => "jonadab@gmail.com"
    ]

   ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$resulting_array = array_filter($array, function ($entry) {
                     return !empty($entry['phone']);
                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter`

```
$array =                     //Your array
$column = 'phone';           //column to filter

$result = array_filter($array, function($o) use($column) {
    return trim( $o[$column] ) !== '' && $o[$column] !== null;
});

print_r( $result );
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Sammy
            [phone] => 2348055643322
            [email] => sammy@abc.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Edwin
            [phone] => 2348099993322
            [email] => eddy@gmail.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Jonadab
            [phone] => 2348066773322
            [email] => jonadab@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Doc: [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Phone value could be null too

Comment: @SaAy I updated the code to not include if the column is empty or null

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, I think the fastest way :

```
$response = [];

foreach ($array as $index => $row) {

    if (strlen($row['phone'])) {
        // keep the original index
        $response [$index]= $row;
    }
}

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: This does not produce the desired array (check the keys).

Comment: Ah you are right, didn't see it. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Vincent: Looping through is not the fastest

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use array_column, array_filter and array_intersect_key.

Array_column and array_filter filters out the phone column that is not empty.
Array_intersect_key will take the keys from $phone and match in $array.

```
$phone = array_filter(array_column($array, "phone"));

$filtered = array_intersect_key($array, $phone);

Var_dump($filtered);
```

https://3v4l.org/R3Tcq

Since the question is "fastest method" see here: https://3v4l.org/nafbq

Comment: I used version 5.6.35

Comment: @SaAy Your question does not state which version you use. Keep in mind to include that as long as you use "old" versions.