# How to filter multidimensional array based on column in a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

Let's say I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array =    [    

    0 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Radiator",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "New",
                        ], 
                        1 => [  
                            "label"     => "Type",  
                            "value"     => "Wall",
                        ],
    ],  
    1 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Airco",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "New",
                        ], 
                        1 => [  
                            "label"     => "Type",  
                            "value"     => "",
                        ], 
    ], 
    2 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Refrigerator",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "Bad",
                        ], 
                        1 => [  
                            "label"     => "Type",  
                            "value"     => "Wall",
                        ], 
    ], 

];
```

I want to filter this array, so it only includes details where the value is not empty. The value for `type` of Airco is empty, so it should not return the detail `type`. The returned array should in this case look like this:

```
$array =    [    

    0 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Radiator",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "New",
                        ], 
                        1 => [  
                            "label"     => "Type",  
                            "value"     => "Wall",
                        ],
    ],  
    1 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Airco",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "New",
                        ],
    ], 
    2 => [  
        "label"    =>  "Refrigerator",  
        "details"  =>   0 => [  
                            "label"     => "Condition",  
                            "value"     => "Bad",
                        ], 
                        1 => [  
                            "label"     => "Type",  
                            "value"     => "Wall",
                        ], 
    ], 

];
```

I know I can filter an array based on an empty column with the following code ([as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543159/how-to-return-arrays-in-which-a-specific-column-contains-non-empty-value-in-mult)):

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($o) use($column) {
    return trim( $o[$column] ) !== '' && $o[$column] !== null;
});
```

but as I have a nested array `details` I'm not quite sure how to adapt this code so it works for my case.

Comment: So what you actually want to filter, is each of those `details` sub-arrays. So loop over your outer array, or use something like `array_map`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `array_filter` is only working on the first level. You would rather want to loop on `details` array too, which you can do using simple foreach loops. The outer loop will loop over all rows and the inner one over `details` of each row.

```
<?php

foreach($array as &$row){
    foreach($row['details'] as $key => $record){
        if(strlen($record['value']) == 0){
            unset($row['details'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/ac0ip)

Comment: Same idea for the reference `&`, except I used `empty` and `array_filter`: https://3v4l.org/tapW8#v8.2.7

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Nice. I am a little skeptical about using empty() since even `0` or `false` or an empty array `[]` would also be considered as an empty value whereas OP seems to only target an empty string.

Comment: Indeed, to be more rigorous (perhaps too?), we can use a strict comparison with the empty string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yep, that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and will resolved the problem

```
$array =    [    

        [  
            "label"    =>  "Radiator",  
            "details"  =>   [[  
                                "label"     => "Condition",  
                                "value"     => "New",
                            ], 
                            [  
                                "label"     => "Type",  
                                "value"     => "Wall",
                            ]],
        ],  
        [  
            "label"    =>  "Airco",  
            "details"  =>   [[  
                                "label"     => "Condition",  
                                "value"     => "New",
                            ], 
                            [  
                                "label"     => "Type",  
                                "value"     => "",
                            ]], 
        ], 
        [  
            "label"    =>  "Refrigerator",  
            "details"  =>   [[  
                                "label"     => "Condition",  
                                "value"     => "Bad",
                            ], 
                            [  
                                "label"     => "Type",  
                                "value"     => "Wall",
                            ]], 
        ], 
    
    ];

Magic is here

    echo "Old Array<pre>";
    print_r($array);//die;
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        $deatilsInside = [];
        foreach($value['details'] as $key1=>$value1) {
            
            if($value1['value'] != '') {
                $deatilsInside[] = $value1;
            }
        }
        $value['details'] = $deatilsInside;
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }

    echo "New Array<pre>";
    print_r($newArray);die;
```

New Array Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [label] => Radiator
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Condition
                            [value] => New
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Type
                            [value] => Wall
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [label] => Airco
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Condition
                            [value] => New
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [label] => Refrigerator
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Condition
                            [value] => Bad
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [label] => Type
                            [value] => Wall
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Please do not make edit suggestions that apply quote formatting to non-quoted content. That is considered an abuse of formatting.

Comment: Can you please let me know which post you are talking about ?, i really appreciate your suggestions

Comment: One example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/35205113

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` and `array_filter` to acomplish this:

```php
$array = [
    [
        "label" => "Radiator",
        "details" => [
            [
                "label" => "Condition",
                "value" => "New",
            ],
            [
                "label" => "Type",
                "value" => "Wall",
            ],
            [
                "label" => "",
                "value" => "",
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        "label" => "Airco",
        "details" => [
            [
                "label" => "Condition",
                "value" => "New",
            ],
            [
                "label" => "Type",
                "value" => "",
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        "label" => "Refrigerator",
        "details" => [
            [
                "label" => "Condition",
                "value" => "Bad",
            ],
            [
                "label" => "Type",
                "value" => "Wall",
            ],
            [
                "label" => "",
                "value" => "asd",
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$filteredArray = array_map(function ($item) {
    if (!empty($item["label"]) && !empty($item["details"])) {
        $details = array_filter($item["details"], function ($detail) {
            return !empty($detail["label"]) && !empty($detail["value"]);
        });

        $item["details"] = array_values($details);
        
        return $item;
    }
    return null;
}, $array);

$filteredArray = array_filter($filteredArray);

print_r($filteredArray);
```

Above code will remove 3rd array from `Radiator`, 2nd array from `Airco` and 3rd array from `Refrigerator` that have empty values for `label`, `value` or both.